# Dropping the basket icon on the website logo

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a website with WordPress. The theme I used is `enfold`.

My problem here is that when I open the website in mobile mode, the cart icon is placed on the logo.

I reviewed all the store-related options, but the problem was not resolved. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Themes usually allow you to write custom css when customize your theme. And you would need to post more specific details such as the html or link so others to take a look at the code and styles, if you want more specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to help you without the actual code. We need at least the HTML that creates the header of your template. But, this will probably do the trick.

1. Resize your browser window to a mobile screen size
2. Right click somewhere on the screen and choose to inspect (if you are with Chrome)
3. Find the cart icon on HTML code and get his class name
4. Add the following CSS rule either on your style.css child theme or on your theme options page for custom CSS

   .cart-css-class {
      float: left;
   }

This will move the icon on the very left side of the screen. You can try different CSS rules like `float: right` or `position: absolute`.

As I said, it's not easy to give a 100% correct answer without a link to the website or the code of the header.

Comment: Which source code should I send?
So you can better guide me.
I can not solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Depends on your template but probably it is the header.php